# MySQL select rows that do not have matching column in other table

Tags: mysql, join, duplicates, unique

I can't seem to figure this out so far. I am trying to join two tables and only select the rows in table A that do not have a matching column in table B. For example, lets assume we have a users table and a sent table.

`users` table has the following columns: `id, username`
`sent` table has the following columns: `id, username`

I want to select all rows from `users` where `username` does not exist in `sent` table. So, if `tom` is in `users` and in `sent` he will not be selected. If he is in `users` but not in `sent` he will be selected. I tried this but it didn't work at all:

```
SELECT pooltest.name,senttest.sentname 
FROM pooltest,senttest 
WHERE pooltest.name != senttest.sentname
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try this SQL:

```
SELECT users.username
FROM  users
LEFT JOIN sent ON sent.username = users.username
WHERE sent.username IS NULL;
```

The better way in my opinion would be:

```
SELECT users.username
FROM  users
LEFT JOIN sent ON sent.id = users.id
WHERE sent.id IS NULL;
```

As both the id fields, would be indexed (primary key I would have thought) so this query would be better optimised than the first one I suggested.

However you may find my first suggestion better for you, it depends on what your requirements are for your application.

Comment: through some other help I also found this to work: SELECT * FROM pooltest LEFT JOIN senttest ON pooltest.name = senttest.sentname WHERE senttest.sentname IS NULL

Answer (score 65):

Typically, you would use `NOT EXISTS` for this type of query

```
SELECT p.Name
FROM   pooltest p
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT s.Name
                   FROM   senttest s
                   WHERE  s.Name = p.Name)
```

An alternative would be to use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and check for `NULL`

```
SELECT p.Name
FROM   pooltest p
       LEFT OUTER JOIN senttest s ON s.Name = p.Name
WHERE  s.Name IS NULL
```

*Note that the implicit join syntax you are using is considered obsolete and should be replaced with an explicit join.*

Answer (score -3):

May be this one can help you ....

I had also the same problem but Solved using this this query

```
INSERT INTO tbl1 (id,name) SELECT id,name from tbl2 where (name) not in(select name from tbl1);
```

hope this one will solve your problem